# 2 column css bottom positioning

Tags: css, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I have a 2 column layout with 100% height of the window size. On the left side I have an image I want to take up 90% of the window size positioned on the bottom of the wrapper. On the right side I have text on top that I want to take up 50% height and below that an image that takes up 50% height. Both images I want responsive to the window size but without overflowing onto other elements in the page.

here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jfarr07/7TctY/2/

HTML

```html
<div class="background">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="leftside">
<div class="imgspacer"></div>
<div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
        <div class="text">lakjsd;lfjas;ldjf;alsdjf;lasdlkfjas;ldjf;alsdjf;laksjdfl;kasjdf</div>
        <div class="rightimage"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
body,html {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

.background {
    background-size:cover;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:#333;
}

.wrapper {
    width:90%; 
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:#fff;
}

.leftside {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}

.imgspacer {
    height:10%; 
    background-color:#222;
    width:100%;
}

.img {
    height:90%;
    background-image:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-CnXnB1TnnhE/UVc8czYpDUI/AAAAAAAAAP8/FXezUtrUeMU/s1600/Jared-allen.jpg);
    width:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.rightside {
    background-color:#888;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    float:right;
}

.text {
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
}

.rightimage {
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    background-image:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-CnXnB1TnnhE/UVc8czYpDUI/AAAAAAAAAP8/FXezUtrUeMU/s1600/Jared-allen.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Also if you would like to see what I am trying to accomplish visit http://www.jonasandnicole.com its the 3rd section with the "we make a difference." That's currently where I'm at but stuff is overflowing and not resizing correctly.

Comment: can you position an element on the bottom of a div without using absolute positioning???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you're missing is `background-size: contain;`. Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/7TctY/5/

EDIT - `background-size: cover;` also works under some circumstances, but in this case it was cutting off the images in an undesirable way.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: Thanks for the offer. I've modified my original answer as to not clutter up the question. Thanks!